# increase speed of LED blink on Raspberry Pi using node.js and onoff

Tags: node.js, twitter, raspberry-pi, gpio, led

I'm trying to alter the interval by using a the variable 'counter'.

The Twitter stream is working and the LED is blinking.

I have removed all the twitter credentials.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
var Gpio = require('onoff').Gpio;
var Twit = require('twit');
var T = new Twit({
    consumer_key:         '' // Your Consumer Key
  , consumer_secret:      '' // Your Co$
  , access_token:         '' // Your Ac$
  , access_token_secret:  '' // Your Access $
});

var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { track: '#blessed, #peace'})

led = new Gpio(17, 'out'),
counter = 500;

stream.start();

var iv = setInterval(function(){
        led.writeSync(led.readSync() === 0 ? 1 : 0);
}, counter);


stream.on('tweet', function(tweet) {

        if(tweet.text.indexOf('#blessed') > -1) {
                console.log("blessed");

                counter += 100;

            }  else if (tweet.text.indexOf('#peace') > -1) {

                console.log("peace");
                counter -= 100;

            }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've made the `setInterval()` call, the timer's locked in, you can't change it. This is how arguments to functions work: Changing them after the fact does nothing. There is no binding to the value supplied, numbers get passed in as a copy.

You'll need to clear and re-set the timer. `setInterval()` returns a handle you can pass through to `clearInterval()` to turn it off. You've captured this, so you just need to use it:

```
var iv;

function blink(interval) {
  if (iv) {
    clearInterval(iv);
  }

  iv = setInterval(function() {
    led.writeSync(led.readSync() === 0 ? 1 : 0);
  }, interval);
}
```

Then use this function to reset it:

```
counter -= 100;
blink(counter);
```

Just make sure you don't go negative.

Comment: I added in a check for the counter and the interval:

Answer (score 0):

I added a check to counter and interval:

```
var Gpio = require('onoff').Gpio;
var Twit = require('twit');
var T = new Twit({
    consumer_key:         '' // Your Consumer Key
  , consumer_secret:      '' // Your Co$
  , access_token:         '' // Your Ac$
  , access_token_secret:  '' // Your Access $
});

var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { track: '#blessed, #peace'})

led = new Gpio(17, 'out'),
counter = 200;

stream.start();

var iv;

function blink(interval) {
  if (iv) {
    clearInterval(iv);
  }
if (interval <= 100) {

interval = 100;

}
console.log("interval = " + interval);

iv = setInterval(function(){
        led.writeSync(led.readSync() === 0 ? 1 : 0);
}, interval);

}

stream.on('tweet', function(tweet) {

        if(tweet.text.indexOf('#blessed') > -1) {
                console.log("blessed");


                counter += 100;
                    if (counter <= 100) {
                counter = 100;
}
                console.log(counter);
                blink(counter);

            }  else if (tweet.text.indexOf('#peace') > -1) {

                console.log("peace");
                counter -= 100;
                if (counter <= 100) {
                counter = 100;
                }
                console.log(counter);
                blink(counter);

            }

});
```